# Рисование в PictureBox при запуске программы

Tags: c#

При запуске программы в PictureBox должны быть нарисованы координатные оси. В конструкторе `Form1` написал следующий код:

```
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 4), pictureBox1.Width / 2, 0, pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 4), 0, pictureBox1.Height / 2, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height / 2);
```

Но при запуске ничего не происходит... Попробовал запихать тот же код в событие формы `Load`, эффекта 0. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предварительно создайте битмапу в пикчурбоксе и обращайтесь к ней

```
  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
  {
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 4), pictureBox1.Width / 2, 0, pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height);
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 4), 0, pictureBox1.Height / 2, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height / 2);
  }
```

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо!